# User Adoption Strategies

Tags: user-admin

This may be a generalized question but I would like to know as to how you drive adoption of users in Salesforce.

What type of different dashboards/reports have you created for different types of audiences (managers/standard users/executives etc.) and how Adoption is increased?

Comment: This a really old question but in case someone still needs help on this, Salesforce now provides a standard feature called In-app guidance: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customhelp_lexguid.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chatter is a great way to drive User Adoption. Ramping Chatter Adoption is recommended by making use of the ENGAGE framework (Explore Business Processes - Navigate Solution - Get Sponsors - Activate Users - Gauge Success - Evolve)

Setting up Chatter Groups where Users can exchange ideas, ask Questions and get answers encourage users to participate and adopt the platform. (Sometimes slightly informal Chatter Groups, such as one's based on the latest going ons around the place of work help people engage more at a personal level, and this gradually translates into greater professional engagement)

Encouraging your star Sales folks with pat-on-the-back Chatter posts (automated or otherwise) when they close a big deal help them gain recognition and make other users aspire for the recognition, so that's another great way.

Once users understand the 360 degree collaboration that the platform affords via Chatter, Content, Customer Portals and of course probably the best CRM solution on the planet, and simple benefits such as massive reduction in email and more intimate and instant feedback, adoption is easier to drive.

You can create various user reports such as User Logins over the past month, three months, etc and comparing trends.

You can get the Chatter Dashboards App from the AppExchange to help you measure Chatter Adoption (http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLqEAO)

Salesforce helps make the Enterprise truly social, and this is a key driving point for user adoption.

Answer (score 3):

Other ideas:

- Make sure to speak with everybody who will use the system, not just management. Management has to buy in but it's the regular office workers who will add value to the system
- Make things simple! Where reasonable, try to remove extra steps
- Have good documentation and training. People can't use what they don't understand
- Try to have some users from various areas be Salesforce champions to help build excitement and adoption
- Get some easy wins

Answer (score 1):

You can also try gamification strategies to boost adoption. Gamification, when done right, is an incredibly powerful answer to boosting Salesforce adoption. This will help you to recognize your power users and encourage others to increase their participation.

Answer (score 1):

Building walls of shame using adoption dashboards like the free appexchange dashboards: http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004gHhLEAU help if they've logged in.

Also, having multiple channels of access help - chatter is excellent at this in that there is a chatter mobile app (if you're byod), there's the chatter desktop app that installs on your laptop or desktop, and then there's chatter tab within your org.

You can also use work.com's gamification system of badges to incent users through common sets of goals.

I'm also a huge proponent of simplifying user interface - make the home tab as simple as possible for people with the least amount of widgets to help drive them to drill down into the object tabs.